# How to set timeout for parser when it takes too long?

Tags: parsing, timeout, antlr

I'm using ANTLR4 in C# with the following code sample:

```cs
    AntlrInputStream antlrStream = new AntlrInputStream(text);
    MyLexer myLexer = new(new AntlrInputStream());
    myLexer.SetInputStream(antlrStream);
    CommonTokenStream myTokens = new CommonTokenStream(myLexer);
    parser = new MyParser(myTokens)
     {
       BuildParseTree = true,
     };
    IParseTree tree = parser.startRule();
```

Class `MyLexer`/`MyParser` are derived from the classes `Lexer`/`Parser` of Anlr4.Runtime and were auto generated by ANTLR4.

In some rare cases, with specific text, `startRule()` takes forever and never finishes. I want to be able to set some kind of a "Timeout" for the parsing and throw an Exception.

Any advice what is the recommended way to do it?

Comment: There's no such feature in the ANTLR4 runtime and you should ask yourself, why you need that at all. What's wrong in your grammar that it causes a long parsing time? Do you see any runtime error (memory exhausted, max recursion etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this temporarily a while back. You can essentially create a wrapper over the generated parser and override one of the methods. I use ANTLR with Kotlin, so excuse the below example.

```
class InterruptibleParser : YourParser() {

  override fun enterRule() {
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        throw InterruptedException()
    }
    return super.enterRule()
  }
}
```

I tried it with either `enterRule`, or `consume`, or `getContext` -- I don't remember which function gets called frequently enough.

But with the above working, you can instantiate the parser and interrupt its thread after a certain amount of time. Would likely make your parsing fairly slower (maybe around 25% slower if I'm remembering correctly). Anyways, hope this helps.